# Angular 2 type object in send services

Tags: angular, typescript

**My Component**

```
let user:{};    
let visited:{};

send(){
this.ns.sendAuthorization(this.user.name, this.visited.name, this.comment)
                  .subscribe(
                    data => this.msgSuccess = data,
                    error => this.msgError = error
                  );
}
```

> error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.

## My Service

```
sendAuthorization(user:string, visited:string, comment?:string): Observable<any> {...}
```

tanks,

EDIT

I managed to solve as follows:

```
this.ns.sendAuthorization(this.user['name'], this.visited['name'], this.comment)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let user:{};      should be      private user={};

let visited:{};   should be      private visited={};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let user = {name: ''};
let visited = {name: ''};
```

or

```
let user = {name: {}};
let visited = {name: {}};
```